# Why ffmpeg command results in blank video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to conver mov file to H264 encoded mp4
Same command converts another mov file just fine.

But fails for a particular mov file. Original video is 29.6MB after conversion I get 966KB

I get the sound and duration right. But all the frames are black even though original video is fine.

Here is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i file3.mov -movflags +faststart -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -vf -threads 0 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "file3.mp4"
```

Here is the result of ffmpeg -i: >ffmpeg.exe -i file3.mov

```
ffmpeg version N-54691-g7f4a1fd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 12 2013 16:31:48 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 39.100 / 52. 39.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 80.101 /  3. 80.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000003077e0] sample aspect ratio already set to
118:81, ignoring 'pasp' atom (10000:7031)
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file3.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30338 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dvvideo (dvpp / 0x70707664), yuv411p, 720x576 [SAR
64:45 DAR 16:9], 28800 kb/s, SAR 118:81 DAR 295:162, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 600 tbn, 25
 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s1
6, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
```

During conversion here is what I see (nothing unusual or no errors):

```
ffmpeg version N-54691-g7f4a1fd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 12 2013 16:31:48 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 39.100 / 52. 39.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 80.101 /  3. 80.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000024aafe0] sample aspect ratio already set to
118:81, ignoring 'pasp' atom (10000:7031)
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file3.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
  Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30338 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: dvvideo (dvpp / 0x70707664), yuv411p, 720x576 [SAR
64:45 DAR 16:9], 28800 kb/s, SAR 118:81 DAR 295:162, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 600 tbn, 25
 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s1
6, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] using SAR=118/81
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] profile High 4:2:2, level 2.1, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] 264 - core 133 r2334 a3ac64b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=umh subme=8 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=50 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'file4a.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv422p, 4
80x320 [SAR 118:81 DAR 59:27], q=-1--1, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000
Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2009-02-12 01:19:22
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16be -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 00000000024b0740] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a s
peedloss
frame=   78 fps=0.0 q=25.0 size=     128kB time=00:00:02.14 bitrate= 487.8kbits/
frame=  113 fps=109 q=25.0 size=     272kB time=00:00:04.27 bitrate= 520.9kbits/
frame=  145 fps= 94 q=25.0 size=     399kB time=00:00:05.36 bitrate= 609.2kbits/
frame=  182 fps= 89 q=25.0 size=     571kB time=00:00:06.45 bitrate= 725.0kbits/
Starting second pass: moving header on top of the file
frame=  200 fps= 70 q=-1.0 Lsize=     965kB time=00:00:08.00 bitrate= 987.2kbits
/s
video:832kB audio:126kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.755121%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] frame I:1     Avg QP:21.14  size: 39885
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] frame P:50    Avg QP:21.80  size:  7412
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] frame B:149   Avg QP:26.25  size:  2960
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  0.0%  1.5% 98.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] mb I  I16..4: 13.7% 46.7% 39.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] mb P  I16..4:  0.5% 19.7%  3.8%  P16..4: 32.8% 11.9
% 14.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:17.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  5.1%  1.3%  B16..8: 14.4%  9.2
%  2.9%  direct: 7.3%  skip:59.8%  L0:42.8% L1:38.3% BI:19.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] 8x8 transform intra:79.4% inter:71.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] direct mvs  spatial:97.3% temporal:2.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 92.8% 80.1% 26.3% inter: 2
4.2% 28.8% 8.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] i16 v,h,dc,p: 64% 17%  3% 16%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  1% 33%  4%  3%  8%
 2% 35%  2% 11%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  3% 23%  5%  4% 11%
 5% 33%  4% 13%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 40% 14%  8%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] ref P L0: 39.9% 10.0% 25.6%  8.7% 15.3%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] ref B L0: 76.9% 15.1%  5.7%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] ref B L1: 96.3%  3.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000000347340] kb/s:851.49
```

Comment: If it appears to be video specific, you may want to ask the same question on the ffmpeg mailing list, and provide a link to the video.

Comment: The input video had dvvideo in mov container. I am trying to convert it to H264 in mp4 container. I will be doing more search in google to see if it gives me anything.

Comment: Not sure but have you try to follow the recommendation made by the encoder, look in the output log , it says that the DV video will be decode as 411 and that it will be good if you specify "-pix_fmt yuv420" (after the input file I remember correctly ) because it seem that ffmpeg had perform 411 to 422 conversion but I don't know if x264 support that format and if it is it would be for a given profile not the main .

Comment: forget my remark about the profile x264 choose the correct profile based on the input

Comment: do you still see concern for yuv411 vs yuv420. I saw it but was not sure if that could cause all frames to be black. Video runs for the same length but it all black. I am trying to upload the video to youtube as a test but youtube is running for 10 mins. Looks like youtube not liking the file either.

Comment: I added -pix_fmt yuv420 but ffmpeg complains saying unknown format.

Comment: Youtube said this: We did not recognize the format of this file, but we will try to process it anyway. See this article on recommended formats for more information.

Comment: -pix_fmts should show all pels formats. if I am right it would be yuv420p for planar